# Calculate average of several columns and print the results in new file

Tags: awk

I'm quite an awk beginner and have the following problem. I have a file with several columns that contain data like this:

```
1 2 3 6

2 3 4 7

4 5 6 8
```

Now I want to calculate the average of every column and write the result in a new file, e.g. newfile.txt where the averages are listed (does not matter if row or column):

```
2
3
5
7
```

Thank you very much!

Stephan

Comment: how it produces 5 for the third column?

Comment: Are you intentionally using integer division to determine the mean, or do you want floating point output?

Comment: Is there really a blank line between each data line in your input file?

Comment: @ Avinash Raj: As i mentioned blow, I unfortunately miscalculated! I'm sorry for that. It needs a computer to do the right calculations ;-)
@ Tom Fenech: the format does not matter, the (wrong) numbers were chosen randomly
@ Ed Morton: no, there's no blank line between the data lines. I had some problems to format the text (this was my first post on stackoverflow)

Comment: @StephanK Consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it if it helped you resolve your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For average I get this:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i} NF{c++} END {for (j=1;j<i;j++) print a[j]/c}' file
2.33333
3.33333
4.33333
7
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I miscalculated!
Thanks for your help, the awk line works great!