# awk: subtract the last from the first element of each column and print results

Tags: awk

I have the following question about awk. I have a file with some columns, like

```
1 5 2

6 1 8

7 9 9
```

I want to calculate the difference between the last and the first element of every column: `7-1=6`, `9-5=4`, `9-2=7`. The results should be printed in another file, like

```
6

4

7
```

Thanks for your help!
Stephan

Comment: What have you tried to do this? This is a fairly straightforward application of awk.

Comment: It should take you about 30 seconds to modify the previous answer you got for a very similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/25708518/1745001) to answer this one. If not, then we are not helping you by providing answers. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

You create an array iterating over each elements of the first line and then in the END block you iterate again subtracting the column with values from array.

```
awk '
  NR==1 { 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
      a[i] = $i 
  }
  END { 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
      print $i - a[i] > ("another.file") 
  }
' file
```

```
$ cat another.file 
6
4
7
```